# Any followup to bad edit approvals?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

[This edit](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/13363), made by an anonymous user, is just junk.  All it consisted of was making the title *worse*.  Yet two out of three editors who saw it approved it.

Is there any kind of followup that can be done, other than re-editing the title or rolling back the change?

Answer (score 2):

Start by rolling back the change (or re-editing, as has been done in this case).

Then, if the edit was *blatantly* bad - or the reviewers have a history of approving bad edits - you can flag for moderator attention and ask them to have a look. If you're flagging because of the reviewers' history, be sure to include specific details (links!) to edits that shouldn't have been approved.

If need-be, moderators can give the reviewers a sanity-check.